# Can I improve read only perfomance using View on my DataBase and EF?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, view, linq-to-entities

I use SQL 2008 Linq and Entity Framework 4.

In my DataBase I have a table called CmsContents.
This table has many fields like `Title`, `CategoryId` and some pretty heavy like `HtmlCode`.

In many part of my Front end I need display only **some field** of my table CmsContents like example only the `Title` and `CategoryId` in descent order.

**Question:**
Can I improve read only performance using a partial View for my Table CmsContents (that exclude the filed: `HtmlCode`)?
So I would map this View to my Model in EF and query with Linq to get the desidred result in the front-end.

My aim is to improve performance and avoiding working with AnonymousType in my Linq to Entity queries.

Let me know what do you think.

Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select only the fields you require, that way you would not need to load un-necessary data. It does not have to be anonymous. 
Example:

```
var result = from c in dbContext.CmsContents select new CmsContent
{Title = c.Title, CategoryId = c.CategoryId}
```

Edit: please try this on your code, this should work if your .CmsContents is IEnumerables, which I think it is.

```
    var contents = context.CmsGroupsTypes
.Single(g => g.GroupTypeId == 1)
.CmsContents
.Select(cms=>new CmsContent{Title = cms.Title, CategoryId = cms.CategoryId})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I never saw your syntax before, sounds pretty cool. How I can apply the same on this my code? var contents = context.CmsGroupsTypes.Single(g => g.GroupTypeId == 1).CmsContents;